# oracle sql split columns by type

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have got a table containing material types:

```
id  type    mat_number   description      count
------------------------------------------------
a   mat_1   123456       wood type a        5 
a   mat_2   333333       plastic type a     8
b   mat_1   654321       wood type b        7
c   mat_2   444444       plastic type c    11
d   mat_1   121212       wood type z        8
d   mat_2   444444       plastic type c     2
d   mat_2   555555       plastic type d     3
```

with SQL I want to create list as follows:

```
id  mat_1     desciption      count  mat_2     description      count
-------------------------------------------------------------------
a   123456    wood type a     5      333333    plastic type c   8
b   654321    wood type b     7      null
c   null                             444444    plastic type c   11 
d   121212    plastic type c  8      444444    plastic type c   2
d   null                             555555    plastic type c   3
```

Is that possible with not too much effort?

Comment: How about your effort?

Comment: According which rules you want get rows for `d`? Why  `121212  444444`, but for second mat_2 you have null `null    555555 `? Why not `121212  444444`, `121212  555555` for example?

Comment: because it's a customer requirement.

Comment: Instead of having columns for each values, will it work for you to have a single column having comma separated values?

Comment: is it also possible to pivot complet lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first of all compute a row number for each id and type grouping, then pivoting is easy:

```
with sample_data as (select 'a' id, 'mat_1' type, 123456 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'a' id, 'mat_2' type, 333333 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'b' id, 'mat_1' type, 654321 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'c' id, 'mat_2' type, 444444 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'd' id, 'mat_1' type, 121212 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'd' id, 'mat_2' type, 444444 mat_number from dual union all
                     select 'd' id, 'mat_2' type, 555555 mat_number from dual)
select id,
       mat_1,
       mat_2
from   (select id,
               type,
               mat_number,
               row_number() over (partition by id, type order by mat_number) rn
        from   sample_data)
pivot (max(mat_number)
       for (type) in ('mat_1' as mat_1, 'mat_2' as mat_2))
order by id, rn;

ID      MAT_1      MAT_2
-- ---------- ----------
a      123456     333333
b      654321           
c                 444444
d      121212     444444
d                 555555
```

Comment: perfect! that's exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you very mach.

Comment: this is also a very good example of how to use the pivot function!

Comment: is it also possible to pivot complet lines?

Comment: If you have a different question to what has already been answered, you should ask a new question, rather than editing this one so that the answer no longer fits. To answer your question, yes, it's probably possible. If you can't work out how to do it, post a new question, where we'd be happy to help. I'd also suggest rolling back your edits to your question to remove the extra data you added, so that other people searching for a similar answer don't end up confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a standard **PIVOT** query. Your output seems wrong though.

For example,

**Table**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

ID TYPE  MAT_NUMBER
-- ----- ----------
a  mat_1     123456
a  mat_2     333333
b  mat_1     654321
c  mat_2     444444
d  mat_1     121212
d  mat_2     444444
d  mat_2     555555

7 rows selected.
```

**PIVOT query**

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   (SELECT id, mat_number, type
  3          FROM   t)
  4  PIVOT  (MAX(mat_number) AS mat FOR (TYPE) IN ('mat_1' AS A, 'mat_2' AS b))
  5  ORDER BY ID;

I      A_MAT      B_MAT
- ---------- ----------
a     123456     333333
b     654321
c                444444
d     121212     555555
```

Comment: i had same idea before asking my question. it's a very elegant way. but here i miss second row for 'd'. d (null) 444444

Comment: @user Yes, I missed that. You need to rank mat_number in each id. That's what Boneist has suggested(I guess).

Answer (score 0):

My query can give you ouptut like

```
Id      mat_number  
- ------------------
a     123456,333333
b     654321
c     444444
d     121212,444444,555555
```

See this query if it helps

```
select id,rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e,s3.mat_number,',') order by s3.type ).extract ('//text()'), ' ,' ) mat_number 
from t s3
group by id
```

Comment: But OP doesn't want string aggregation.